# Porting a UNIX daemon to a Windows Service

Tags: c, visual-studio, windows-services, daemon

I wrote a UNIX daemon, in C, which I want to port to Windows.
My target is Windows 10.

When I search on how to create a Windows service, I am met by an [approach using .NET and C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) which I both want to avoid at all cost.

How can I make a simple straightforward service in C, without kitchen sinks that Microsoft tries to unload on me? If I really have to, I would consider C++, but C# and .Net are simply taking it too far.

I'm fine with switching to a different compiler too, if this is easier outside of VisualStudio. (Currently I am using Visual Studio 2019, latest update.)

NOTE: My Linux daemon just has one dependency: libhidapi which is available for Windows.

### UPDATE

No C++ templates available.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. These are way too different. You will need to rewrite the functionality the Windows way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok, thanks! Wasn't a small C program the way it used to be under Windows, pre dot Net?

Comment: @EugeneSh.  It's not that hard to write a service for Windows in C - I'd post an answer if I had access to the framework I wrote for a customer quite a while ago.  The way a service starts is a bit different - IIRC it's not from `main()` nor even any of Microsoft's "vendor-lock-in" versions of `main()`.  Start with the [`CreateService()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicea) to build your service.  Also, more than a few examples:  https://www.google.com/search?q=write+windows+service+c+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @AndrewHenle I did not say it is hard, I said that it is quite different from Linux/Unix, so direct porting would be a challenge

Comment: I wrote services for NT on a previous life (circa 1999) ... I can do some spelunking and try to remember how it worked. Give me some days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes down to creating two different applications (.exe)

One to run the service using `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` where the dispatching function calls `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx()` to register a controller.

One to install the service using `CreateService()`

It is possible to skip on the installer, and use the `sc` command line utility for that, which is part of the OS.

See [full example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus).